# Combine RxSwift timer and interval observables into a single observable with completion

Tags: swift, timer, countdown, reactive-programming, rx-swift

I'd like to create an observable that behaves behaves something like this.

```
var count = 0

func setupCountdownTimer() {
  let rx_countdownTimer = CountdownTimer.observable(5)

  rx_countdownTimer >- subscribeNext {
    secondsRemaining in
    println(secondsRemaining) // prints 5, then 4, 3, 2, 1, then finally 0
    count = secondsRemaining
  }

  rx_countdownTimer >- subscribeCompleted {
    println(count) // prints 5, assuming countdownTimer stopped 'naturally'
  }
}

@IBAction func stop(sender: UIButton) {
  rx_countdownTimer.sendCompleted() // Causes 2nd println above to output, say, 3, if that's how many seconds had elapsed thus far.
}
```

It seems like I should be able to somehow combine a [timer observable](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/timer.html) and an [interval observable](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/interval.html) here, but I can't seem to figure out the correct strategy for doing this. New to Rx, so I'm open to the possibility that I'm going about it all wrong. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is that like this?

[CountdownTimer.swift](https://gist.github.com/hisui/e242ec8f8feca5b5ee54)

```
var timer = CountdownTimer(5)
var count = 0

func setupCountdownTimer() {
    timer.observable >- subscribeNext { n in
        println(n) // "5", "4", ..., "0" 
        self.count = n
    }
    timer.observable >- subscribeCompleted {
        println(self.count)
    }
}

@IBAction func stop(sender: UIButton) {
    timer.sendCompleted()
}
```

Comment: Ack! I was on vacation when you responded, and the bounty expired before I could assign it to you. Sorry, findall. Thanks for the help. Do you have any suggestions for learning RxSwift in more depth? I've been drowning in the docs and source. :-S